# Data binding checkboxes in svelte

Tags: forms, checkbox, svelte

in a svelte/sapper form I want to send data to a user model

```
<input type="text" bind:value={user.label}>
```

..works as expected. But how to send user.offer_ids

```
let offer_ids = [];

{#each offers as offer}
  <label>
   <input type=checkbox bind:group={offer_ids} value="{offer.id}">{offer.label}
  </label>
{/each}
```

I can't find any svelte sample how to do this job, which I think is basic in forms.. Thanks for help

May be it was unclear..I want to send data to Json:

```
<form>

<input type="text" bind:value={user.label}> //gives data to 'user'

{#each offers as offer}
  <label>
   <input type=checkbox bind:group={offer_ids} value="{offer.id}">{offer.label}
  </label>
{/each}
```

//how to get all selected ids to 'user'

```
</form>
```

Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: What do you expect from setting a `group` attribute on a checkbox type input?

Answer (score 3):

With checkboxes, we bind to `checked` instead of `value`:

```
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    let flag = false
</script>

<style>
    .highlighted {
        color: red
    }
</style>

<h1 class:highlighted={flag}>Hello {name}!</h1>
<label for="checkbox">Highlight header</label>
<input id="checkbox" type='checkbox' bind:checked={flag}/>
```

Edit

The offer model should have a selected or checked state. Then you can bind the checkbox to that:

```
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    let offers = [
        {id: 1, name: 'One', checked: false},
        {id: 2, name: 'Two', checked: false},
        {id: 3, name: 'Three', checked: false},
    ]
</script>

{#each offers as offer, index (offer.id)}
    <label for={'checkbox'+offer.id}>{offer.name}</label>
  <input id={'checkbox'+offer.id} bind:checked={offer.checked} type='checkbox'/>
{/each}

<div>
    {offers.filter(offer => offer.checked).map(offer => offer.name)}
</div>
```

Here, we display three checkboxes and the text below prints the names of the selected offers on the screen.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/461fea432dc54ed0a744afc4e05bf34b?version=3.22.3

Comment: Thanks Andreas, may be you read my edited question again. I want to get all  id's from the clicked checkboxes into a Json hash, and not to display them.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for the work.
..not really helps..I don't want to display the data but get them into Json as I send the form to an API endpoint.

What I need is this:

{method: "POST", headers: {…}, body: "{"user":{"name":"Werner","offer_ids":1,2,5}}"}
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json"}

I have to fill the let offer_ids=[] with the checked id's and bind them to 'user'
Hope this gets more clear now

;-)

Comment: It's clear to me, that you don't want to display them on the screen. This was just a demo to show how to do the binding. When you look at the code that I used to print the 'offer names' then you could use something similar to print the id's instead or add them to that request payload object, when you press your 'send' button or whatever :)

Comment: Looks like the latest Svelte REPL tutorials now has this reference for anyone else that needed a closer look: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-block-bindings

Answer (score 0):

so my solution now:

```
let offer_ids = [];

<form>

 {#each offers as offer, i (offer.id)}
  <label>
    <input type=checkbox bind:group={offer_ids} value="{offer.id}">{offer.label}
  </label><br/>
 {/each}

</form>
enter code here
```

and in the function...

```
 async function publish() {

    user.offer_ids = offer_ids
    const response = await (api.post('users', {user}));
```